# How to run a Desktop application(TPT) from JAVA API?

Tags: java

I have a java code to run an application using Java API. API plug-in is installed and activated in the application. But When I run the java code in Command Prompt, it is showing error, without opening the TPT application. Not getting even .class file also.

Could anyone help me with this?

Here is the code:

```
package com.piketec.tpt.api.example;

import java.io.File;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import com.piketec.tpt.api.ApiException;
import com.piketec.tpt.api.ExecutionConfiguration;
import com.piketec.tpt.api.ExecutionStatus;
import com.piketec.tpt.api.OpenResult;
import com.piketec.tpt.api.PlatformConfiguration;
import com.piketec.tpt.api.Project;
import com.piketec.tpt.api.RemoteCollection;
import com.piketec.tpt.api.TestCaseExecutionStatus;
import com.piketec.tpt.api.TestCaseExecutionStatus.TestCaseStatus;
import com.piketec.tpt.api.TptApi;
import com.piketec.tpt.api.properties.PropertyMap;

/**
 * This example will open the given TPT-File in TPT. Then it will try to execute every execution
 * configuration. It will print the current status to System.out and if error occure it will print
 * the logs as well. Further it will cancel each execution, if the the number of pendig tests is <=
 * 2.
 *
 * @author Joachim Kuhnert, PikeTec GmbH
 *
 */
public class ExampleTestExecution {

  // TODO: Adjust the file path
  /**
   * The TPT-File to load. Adjust this to an valid one!
   */
  private static final File TPT_FILE = new File("VRT_CPC_nG_v1.13_167_M274.tpt");

  private static final String HOST = "localhost";

  private static final int PORT = 1099;

  private static final String BINDING_NAME = "TptApi";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (!(TPT_FILE.exists() && TPT_FILE.isFile())) {
      System.out.println("Please check that the field TPT_FILE points to a valid file");
      return;
    }
    try {
      Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(HOST, PORT); // get Server/RMI-Registry
      TptApi remoteApi = (TptApi)registry.lookup(BINDING_NAME); // get TPT-API
      OpenResult openResult = remoteApi.openProject(TPT_FILE.getAbsoluteFile()); // open attached
                                                                                 // tpt-File
      Project project = openResult.getProject(); // recieve the now open project

      RemoteCollection<ExecutionConfiguration> executionConfigurations =
          project.getExecutionConfigurations();
      for (PlatformConfiguration pCfg : project.getPlatformConfigurations().getItems()) {
        PropertyMap properties = pCfg.getProperties();
        System.out.println(properties);
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
      }
      for (ExecutionConfiguration execCfg : executionConfigurations.getItems()) {
        System.out.println("//// Running execution configuration " + execCfg.getName() + " ////");
        ExecutionStatus execStatus = remoteApi.run(execCfg); // execute the execution configuration

        while (execStatus.isPending()) { // wait so the execution has a chance to start
          Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

        int pending;
        int size = execStatus.getAllTestCases().size();
        while (execStatus.isRunning()) {
          pending = execStatus.getNumberOfPendingTestCases();
          // print some status information
          System.out.println(size - pending + " von " + execStatus.getNumberOfAllTestCases());
          System.out.println(testCasesToStatusString(execStatus.getAllTestCases()));
          System.out.println("Total Status: " + execStatus.getTotalExecutionStatus().name());
          if (pending <= 2) { // cacel showcase: don't execute last 2 testcases (3rd last execution
            // is likely to be interrupted and fails in this case)
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("//////////////////////////");
            System.out.println("//// CANCEL EXECUTION ////");
            System.out.println("//////////////////////////");
            System.out.println();
            execStatus.cancel();
          } else {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
          }
        }

        // print the logs for failed testcases
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("//// Printing logs of failed Testcases ////");
        for (TestCaseExecutionStatus testCaseExecutionStatus : execStatus.getAllTestCases()) {
          if (testCaseExecutionStatus.getStatus() == TestCaseStatus.ResultError
              || testCaseExecutionStatus.getStatus() == TestCaseStatus.ResultFailed) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(
                "[FAILED] test case: \"" + testCaseExecutionStatus.getTestcase().getName() + "\"");
            printStringList(testCaseExecutionStatus.getStatusLog());
          }
        }
        System.out.println();
      }

      project.closeProject(); // close the project

    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println(e);
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static String testCasesToStatusString(Collection<TestCaseExecutionStatus> stati) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (TestCaseExecutionStatus status : stati) {
      if (sb.length() > 0) {
        sb.append(", ");
      }
      try {
        sb.append(status.getStatus().toString());
      } catch (ApiException | RemoteException e) {
        sb.append("<error>");
      }
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  private static void printStringList(List<String> list) {
    for (String str : list) {
      System.out.println("   " + str);
    }
  }

}
```

Here is the error in the command prompt:

```
                                              ^
  symbol:   variable TestCaseStatus
  location: class ExampleTestExecution
ExampleTestExecution.java:98: error: cannot find symbol
              || testCaseExecutionStatus.getStatus() == TestCaseStatus.ResultFailed) {
                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable TestCaseStatus
  location: class ExampleTestExecution
ExampleTestExecution.java:118: error: cannot find symbol
    for (TestCaseExecutionStatus status : stati) {
         ^
  symbol:   class TestCaseExecutionStatus
  location: class ExampleTestExecution
ExampleTestExecution.java:124: error: cannot find symbol
      } catch (ApiException | RemoteException e) {
               ^
  symbol:   class ApiException
  location: class ExampleTestExecution
27 errors
```

The above error is just a part of the error.

How can I open a application using Java API in command prompt?

Comment: So you get an error and you want us to help you solve it, yet you don't tell us **what the error is**? Give us the **exact** error message. Also: What does your code look like? What is TPT?

Comment: Sorry, for the inconvience. TPT is a desktop application, which is bascially used for testing the c code and also in Automotive industry.

Comment: This is a java compiler error. It tells you that some symbols could not be found while compiling. Those symbols are `TestCaseStatus`, `TestCaseExecutionStatus`, and `ApiException`. The code seems to be okay, because those classes are among the imports. A typical cause for your error is a missing dependency in the classpath. I guess you will need to include something like a TPT-Java-API jar in your classpath. But I have no clue about TPT.

Comment: @lupz thank you so much, I got it now

Comment: @surendrakumarAM nice to hear that you solved your problem! Please consider to answer (and accept) your own question with some details (e.g. which jar/library was missing, how to add it etc) in order to help future visitors and to finish up this thread. Happy coding :)